# Как заменить дубликат в SQL запросе

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Есть 4 таблицы.

**Author** - Здесь имена исполнителей

```
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | Fedor|
-------------
| 2  | Alex |
```

**Track** - Здесь название треков

```
| id | name |
-------------
| 1  | ляля |
-------------
| 2  | олол |
```

**Track_cover** - Здесь название картинки трека

```
| id | id_track | name   |
--------------------------
| 1  | 1        |ляля.jpg|
--------------------------
| 2  | 2        |олол.jpg|
```

**Composition** - А здесь все вместе собрано

```
| id | id_track | id_author |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 1        | 1         |
-----------------------------
| 2  | 2        | 1         |
-----------------------------
| 3  | 2        | 2         |
```

Но есть небольшая проблемка. Есть треки, где авторов два и более, в примере выше я описал это, когда у трека №2 "олол" два автора, Fedor и Alex.

SQL запрос будет выдавать следующее

```
| track_name | track_author | track_url |
-----------------------------------------
| ляля       | Fedor        | ляля.jpg  |
-----------------------------------------
| олол       | Fedor        | олол.jpg  |
-----------------------------------------
| олол       | Alex         | олол.jpg  |


SELECT track.name as track_name, author.name as track_author, track_cover.name as track_url FROM composition INNER JOIN track ON composition.id_track = track.id INNER JOIN author ON composition.id_author = author.id INNER JOIN track_cover ON track.id = track_cover.id_track
```

Как лучше поступить в этом случае? Как сделать так, что бы был следующий результат:

1. Fedor - ляля
2. Fedor & Alex - олол

Какими средствами, лучше добиться данного результата? SQL, PHP, JS?
Правильно ли я разбил данные на 4 таблицы, или надо было меньше?

Comment: делать в запросе group by до трека, собирать авторов в список через запятую например соответствующей агрегатной функцией. В разных диалектах sql используются разные функции, например string_agg в postgresql, group_contact в MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) в помощь:

```
SELECT track.name AS track_name
, GROUP_CONCAT(author.name ORDER BY author.name ASC SEPARATOR ' & ') AS track_author
, track_cover.name AS track_url
FROM composition 
INNER JOIN track ON composition.id_track = track.id 
INNER JOIN author ON composition.id_author = author.id 
INNER JOIN track_cover ON track.id = track_cover.id_track
GROUP BY track.id
```

Comment: На основе чего вы поняли, что автор вопроса использует MySQL ? (функция group_contact есть только в нем)

Comment: То что нужно :)
Только у меня ошибка выходит:

Errors
Result: near "ORDER": syntax error
At line 1:
SELECT track.name AS track_name
, GROUP_CONCAT(author.name ORDER

Немного переделал, и получилось так:
...
, GROUP_CONCAT(author.name) as track_author
...

И все заработало как надо, но только там запятая, а не '&'. В интернете нашел такую функцию как SEPARATOR, получилось следующее:
...
, GROUP_CONCAT(author.name SEPARATOR ' & ') as track_author
...

И все равно ошибка:
Errors
At line 1:
SELECT track.name AS track_name
, GROUP_CONCAT(author.name SEPARATOR

Answer (score 0):

Я полагаю что, правильно разбито на 4 таблицы.

Существует функция [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) которая способна конкатенировать агрегированные результаты колонки. В вашем случае будет нечто такое:

```
SELECT ... GROUP_CONCAT(author.name) ... FROM ... GROUP BY track.id
```

Но, имейте в виду, у этой функции есть ограничение на объем выводимых данных. По умолчанию 1024 символа для каждого объединения - для каждой выводимой строки. Но это может быть настроено иначе на разных серверах.

Если нужен более стабильный результат, то придется делать 2 запроса и объединять все вручную.

Comment: На основе чего вы поняли, что автор вопроса использует MySQL ? (функция group_contact есть только в нем)

Comment: Я предположил на основе того, что автор использует PHP, хотя могу и ошибаться. Но если автор уточнит диалект SQL, я возможно дополню ответ.

Comment: Пока использую SQLite3

Comment: Данная функция есть и в SQLite с такими же ограничениями.

Comment: Еще вопрос, а можно сделать так, что бы каждый автор был в отдельном столбце, а не перечислялись через запятую. Я так подумал, как реализовать поиск по автором. Если бы они были в отдельном столбце, то я бы мог их раскидать по разным блокам и уже при клике на определенного автора, выдавать весь список его творчества.

Comment: В общем случае так сделать не получиться. Смотрите, если у вас есть ограничение на количество авторов в треке (например не более 3х авторов на трек), то можно в таблицу авторов добавить порядок их следования в треке (1, 2, 3) и затем трижды объединить таблицу авторов ваш запрос и в каждую колонку вывести автора с соответствующим порядком. Но в общем случае это не возможно, когда у вас связь в таблице один-к-бесконечности. И потому, далеко не случайно у GROUP_CONCAT - ограничение на длину вывода.

Comment: Еще один глупый вопросик :) Я добавил еще одну таблицу "playlist_composition", там есть три колонки id, id_playlist,id_composition как использовать id_composition в таблице "Composition", которая удовлетворяла бы например такому условию id_playlist=1 в таблице "playlist_composition". Использовать два SELECT'а? Только вот у меня ничего не получается :)

Comment: Я не понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Проще создать новый вопрос.